# How to implement opacity compatible in both IE5 and IE11

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I am trying to render a form with opacity = 0.5 & disable the actions of elements on a button click , it works well in IE11 but fails in IE 5 .

```
<script>
function opaqueForm(){
var form = document.getElementById('myFormName'),s,opacity;
s = form.style;
s.filter = 'alpha(opacity=50)';
s.opacity = 50/100
for(var i=0;i<form.length;i++) form[i].disabled=true;
}
</script>
```

When I tried to check the DOM explorer to see how it is rendered , I see in IE 5 the filter is applied to the form and opacity is not applied . The form is not rendered opaque in IE5.

Can anyone suggest how to style the form to render it opaque in both IE5 and IE11
Thanks in advance for any suggestions & solutions.

Comment: IE 5?  Like for Windows 95?

Comment: IE5? What year are we in?

Comment: IE5 reached end-of-life twenty years ago; support for modern features is going to be.... iffy.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to support IE5 ? If someone asked you this, just say no. It would never be worth spending time to try to support such a graphic feature for a very old browser.

Comment: Thanks @Brewal. some of our legacy microservice apps run on IE 5 . The migration is still in progress to IE 11 edge. So, I would like to implement opacity in both IE 5 and IE 11.

Comment: @Ramya I understand that if an old app supported IE 5 you don't want to break this support. But I would think the other way and urgently ask for any of your users that would still use IE 5 to use something else (for security issues first) and don't bother to code anything more for that browser (it's hard to maintain, test, ...). I know it's not an answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be safe not expending effort supporting a browser that reached end of life two decades ago.

But, for historical curiosity, it turns out (to my surprise) that what you want is actually possible! Versions of Internet Explorer from v5.5 through v8 used a proprietary `-ms-filter` property instead of standards (as is true of many IE features; this was during the "[Embrace and Extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)" era.)

The [syntax for opacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms532910(v=vs.85)) looked something like this:

```
{ filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity = 100 ... ) ... }
```